# delete old log files except the last one (alphanumerically sorted)

Tags: shell, files, rm

I have a number of log files in the form:

```
log.2014-02-19-10_24_22
```

I.e. log.YYYY-MM-DD-H24_MI_SS

The date that's part of the log file's name is when the log file was first created. So at any given moment in time I can have the following log files in my directory:

```
log.2014-02-19-10_18_54
log.2014-02-19-10_21_20
log.2014-02-19-10_23_11
etc.
```

Now I have a script that's invoked by a cronjob and that deletes "old" log files:

```
$ cat delete-old-rotated-logs 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* -type f -mmin +1800 -exec rm {} \;
```

The problem I am facing is that sometimes the process that's logging has crashed so the "latest" log file also becomes "old" after some time (since no process is writing on it) and gets deleted, thus losing me the trace. How can I re-write the `delete-old-rotated-logs` script so that it deletes old files except the last one (or the last `N`) ? For the ordering one can use both the filename itself or the modification timestamp (more robust).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* -type f -mmin +1800 |
  sort | head -n -1 | xargs rm
```

Or if you want to use `mtime` instead of the filename:

```
find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* -type f -mmin +1800 -exec ls -t {} + |
  tail -n +2 | xargs rm
```

From @Stephane's comments, a more robust approach would be to do:

```
IFS=$'\n'
set -f
rm $(
  find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* ! -name $'*\n*' -type f -mmin +1800 |
  sort | head -n -1 )
```

Or for POSIX shell (still requires GNU tools):

```
IFS='
'
ex_newline='*
*'
set -f
rm $(
  find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* ! -name "$ex_newline" -type f -mmin +1800 |
  sort | head -n -1 )
```

A single (robust) pipeline can be used with a recent version of GNU `sed`/`sort` (and GNU find as with all of the above):

```
find /home/foo -maxdepth 1 -iname log\* -type f -mmin +1800 -print0 |
  sort -z | sed -z '$d' | xargs -0 rm
```

Comment: For `xargs`, newline is not the only problematic character. space, tab, single quote, double quote and backslash are as well.

Comment: Your `ls -t`-based one would not work properly if `find` runs more than one `ls` (if the list of files is big enough that it wants to split it in several `ls` invocations).

Comment: Note that none of `-maxdepth`, `-iname`, `-mmin`, `head -n -1` are POSIX anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I know about that one, I was just showing the shell syntax. The `xargs` issue is new to me though, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`bash`/`ksh93`/`zsh`:

```
n=5        # Maximum number of files to keep
cd /home/foo || exit
files=(log.*)
((${#files[@]} <= n)) ||
  rm -f -- "${files[@]:0:${#files[@]}-n}"
```

With `zsh`, it can be simplified to:

```
n=5
rm -f /home/foo/log.*(N[1,-n-1])
```

And if you want to only consider the files that are over 30 hours old:

```
n=5
rm -f /home/foo/log.*(Nmh+30[1,-n-1])
```

POSIXly:

```
n=5
cd /home/foo || exit
set -- log.*
i=$#
while [ "$i" -gt "$n" ]; do
  set -- "$@" "$1"
  shift
  i=$(($i - 1))
done
shift "$i"
rm -f -- "$@"
```